# Single word or expression for something to to be or going to be

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is it possible to express in a single word or with a short expression that something prevails or will soon prevail?

For example:

1. > This house has already been sold or will be sold tomorrow for sure
2. > Your application has been accepted or will be accepted in a minute

Comment: You won't have any term that says exactly both those things because the former means it has happened and the latter means it hasn't yet. Phrasings like "consider the house sold," "the house is as good as sold," the house's sale is imminent," and "the house will sell presently" don't indicate the house has already sold but do express the sureness and soonness you seem to want to convey. You might try, "By this time tomorrow, the house will have sold," which indicates it'll already be sold by then, leaving it open to the possibility it is now, albeit why you wouldn't know that, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As good as**

From [Farlax Dictionary of Idioms via TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+good+as):

> 1. The same quality as; comparable to. Just use this toothpaste—it's as good as that fancy brand you usually get.
> 2. Essentially; nearly the same as. The turkey is as good as finished, so please start setting the table. I'm as good as

Or in your examples:

> This house is as good as sold.
>
> Your application is as good as accepted.